# April 2021 CEO blog post contains inaccessible images

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog, accessibility

When scrolling through the April 2021 blog post by the CEO, "[Accelerating Stack Overflow’s transformation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/26/accelerating-stack-overflows-transformation/)", I happened to have images turned off. While reading, there was a graph included that charted "Teams growth from March 15th to April 15th" - but for me, with images turned off (or for anyone using a screen reader), it showed up as a blank patch of space. You can tell there's supposed to be something there, but for anyone who can't see the image, you have no idea what it's supposed to show.

Also, later on, there's an image with a list of customers that use Stack Overflow for Teams. This also has no alt text or anything; I didn't even notice it was there until I turned on images and scrolled through the post again.

Could you please add some alt text? It's a basic accessibility tenet (that the company blog has repeatedly run afoul of).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this one out to us. I've updated it with alt text. Let us know if there are other images that need alt text.