# Images in "Agility starts with trust" blog post have no alt text, making it less accessible

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, accessibility, alt-text

> If we have any hope of making technology more diverse and inclusive, we have to make technical learning resources accessible to all.

That's a direct quote from "[Agility starts with trust](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/04/28/agility-starts-with-trust/)", the latest quarterly CEO update.

Immediately before that line happens to be an image. It says something about what makes developers happy and unhappy at work.

[image: Screenshot of the blog post showing the image]

However, when I disable images, I am greeted with an accessible, inclusive...

[image: Screenshot of the blog post showing a blank spot where the image was]

...blank space.

As has become a [running theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A294691+alt+text+blog), this blog post is again missing alt text for multiple images included in the post. For a blog post that talks about diversity and inclusion - and accessibility - this is especially ironic, as this is something that has been brought up several times in the past.

Comment: I guess the image is not a technical learning resource ;)

Comment: So instead of *"For a blog post (...) this is especially ironic"* I'd go with the more economical: *"this has happened before"* because it suffices.

Comment: @bad_coder - the point is that it is ironic that a blog post talking about accessibility is itself not accessible. I'm not sure we're using the word "ironic" in the same way.

Comment: @Mithical reading the English you wrote, you're lumping into the irony that this is a recurring mistake. There really isn't any irony worthy of note, just a copy-editing mistake.

Comment: @bad_coder I don't think that we understand the meaning of irony in the same way. Irony is "*a situation that is unusual or amusing because something strange happens, or the opposite of what is expected happens or is true*" ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/irony)). There's nothing rude about it - Mith is saying that it's unusual or amusing that a post talking about focusing on accessibility is not itself accessible. It seems like a completely reasonable usage of the term.

Comment: I edited the title. If you want, you could also make it the same as your previous report ([April 2021 CEO blog post contains inaccessible images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363743/april-2021-ceo-blog-post-contains-inaccessible-images?rq=1)): [April 202**2** CEO blog post contains inaccessible images]

Comment: @Catija I'm certain the Longman's entry is incomplete because it doesn't define the word being applied to a person or their action, [this wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony#Sarcasm) gives a broader overview of the semantics that is based on more sources.

Comment: @Catija What you're referring to is called "Situational Irony", and is the most common and most well known form of irony, the definition of irony itself is.... a bit less straight forward (Outside of that (implying that that is the only form of irony) I of course, agree with you).

Comment: @Justin - I had used a direct quote from the blog post as the title to highlight the discrepancy of speaking about diversity and inclusion and yet not taking those steps for the blog post itself. It's not a big deal, but it was intentional.

Comment: I edited the title as a response to another user's now-deleted comment which mentioned that they had downvoted the question because it had a "distracting and clickbait title".

Comment: *Considering adding [tag:irony] tag*

Answer (score 7):

The alt text for all the images in the blog post have now been added.

Example:

> [image: Screenshot of disabled image with alt text in dark mode]

Comment: Where are the numbers? That's not good alt text for the image because it doesn't convey the same thing as the image text.

Comment: That's a fair point, and I've updated the text to include the same text as the chart.

Comment: Thanks, @Ryan. I've updated the image in my answer.